# Form validators in a separate Dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I was thinking of writing the validators in a separate dart file in order to have a much cleaner code. I did write a new dart file and wrote a string method with a condition but how to initialize the dart file in the validator parameter of textformfield?

```
TextFormField(
       textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
       controller: _articleNumberController,
       validator: Validators.validateName(),
       decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.straighten),
            labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
            labelText: 'Article Number',
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            isDense: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                   ),
                ),
   ),
```

And this is the separate class file of the validator

```
class Validators {
  String validateName(String value) {
    String pattern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Name is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Name must be a-z and A-Z";
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

If i try to initialize in the **validator** as `validator: Validators.validateName()` I'm getting an error as `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String Function(String)'`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add `static` when you initialize your method

```
class Validators {
 static String validateName(String value) {
    String pattern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Name is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Name must be a-z and A-Z";
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And then your code looks like

```
TextFormField(
       textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
       controller: _articleNumberController,
       validator: Validators.validateName,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.straighten),
            labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
            labelText: 'Article Number',
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            isDense: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                   ),
                ),
   ),
```

Comment: I was just going to test this rewrite... glad you beat me to it.  It's generally a code smell when you have `something: (value) => some.function(value),`, because `something: some.function,` is generally the same thing without the extra item on the call stack.  No need to wrap a named function with an anonymous function!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz yes :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this method works for you

```dart
TextFormField(
 textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
 controller: _articleNumberController,
 validator: (value) => Validators.validateName(value),
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.straighten),
 labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
 labelText: 'Article Number',
 contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
 isDense: true,
 border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
   ),
  ),
),

/// class

class Validators {
  static String validateName(String value) {
    String pattern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Name is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Name must be a-z and A-Z";
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this package
https://pub.dev/packages/queen_validators

```dart
import 'package/queen_validators/queen_validators.dart';
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return TextFormField(
     // use qValidator function and provider list of rules to apply on this field
    validator: qValidator([
      IsRequired(),
      IsEmail(),
      MinLength(8),
      MaxLength(30, "optionally you can override the failure if the validation fails"),
    ]),
  );
  }
```